# Mono gets "System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL " on some computers only

Tags: c#, exception, mono

I'm getting the following exception when trying to run Mono applications:

```
Unhandled Exception: [Some exception here -- this part changes] ---> System.ExecutionEngineException: SIGILL
  at System.Collections.Hashtable..ctor (Int32 capacity, Single loadFactor, IHashCodeProvider hcp, IComparer comparer) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Collections.Hashtable..ctor (Int32 capacity, Single loadFactor) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Collections.Hashtable..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at [other calling locations that change]...
```

The exact same system image (literally) has success on some computers, such as in VMWare, and fails with this exception on some other hardware.

p.s. I have seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388410/error-initialising-the-configuration-system-when-creating-tcpclient-in-mono but I already have a machine.config file, and I'm not using mkbundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I had precompiled (ahead of time) binaries that were incompatible.

Comment: I'm getting this error now, what was the solution? I'm using VS 2013, with a Xamaring project. This occurs when trying to deploy to my Android device. I have a very basic "Hello, World" app that is pretty much straight out of the box. Let me know if you have an idea, thanks!